# ¿Cómo asignar un valor decimal en variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de generar una variable de porcentaje en SQL Server, de una tabla  de ordenes que tiene años, al asignar las variables de años obtengo los conteos correctos pero al hacer la asignación a mi variable el resultado es incorrecto.

No requiero más allá de 5 dígitos de precisión

Este es el código que he estado usando

```
DECLARE @Mx_Fy AS INT = (SELECT MAX(Year) FROM My_Table) 
DECLARE @FyM1 AS INT =  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Request)) 
                        FROM My_Table WHERE Year = @Mx_Fy-1)
DECLARE @FyM2 AS INT =  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Request)) 
                        FROM My_Table WHERE Year = @Mx_Fy-2)

--SELECT @FyM1 --> 689
--SELECT @FyM2 --> 472

DECLARE @FcstPct AS FLOAT(5) = @FyM1/@FyM2 

SELECT  @FcstPct --> 1 >:(
```

Desafortunadamente no he podido obtener el valor que busco, que debe de ser 1.45974

En su lugar obtengo esto

[image: Estoy seguro no debe ser 1!!]

¿Podría alguien apoyarme con mi caso??

Comment: Cambia la pregunta a español y con gusto se te ayudará.

Comment: This web site if for Spanish questions only. For English questions try stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: Gracias, cambiado a español

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el motor estipula el tipo de dato en función de los operandos involucrados, en este caso ambos números enteros, por lo que la salida finalmente será un entero. Para evitarlo, podemos convertir previamente cualquiera de los valores en un `FLOAT`:

```
 DECLARE @FcstPct AS FLOAT(5) = @FyM1/CAST(@FyM2 AS FLOAT)
```

O también, involucrar un literal fr coma flotante

```
 DECLARE @FcstPct AS FLOAT(5) = @FyM1/(@FyM2 * 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solamente necesitas convertir uno de los operadores a `FLOAT`, puede ser el dividendo o el divisor, algo así:

```
DECLARE @Mx_Fy INT
DECLARE @FyM1 INT
DECLARE @FyM2 INT
DECLARE @FcstPct FLOAT

SET @FyM1 = 689
SET @FyM2 = 472

SET @FcstPct = @FyM1/CONVERT(FLOAT,@FyM2) 

SELECT  @FcstPct
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26685626a94d543f2eedba469cbc82a7)</kbd>